# Adobe cert E121

Tags: ado

Sorry Everyone! Can you share me material or question to get exam? Thanks!
I have document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/ but it's general and very large. I don't sure can read all them (example: Content management tools
Digital asset management tools
Projects
Forms
Experience fragments and content fragments
Screens
Workflows
Launches
CRXDE Lite
User administration
Multi-site management
Monitoring tools
Versioning
Personalization and context hub
SPA Editor
Tagging
Browser usage
General understanding of the Web
Responsive web design concepts...)

Thanks so much! Thanks!